# Dygraph chart with smooth lines

Tags: javascript, smoothing, spline, dygraphs, edges

Recently I started using Dygraph for the charts on my website, and everything works just fine. However, purely as an aestetic change, I'd like to make the lines that are drawn based on my data to be smooth, and not with sharp edges.

I looked up if dygraph had an option for a spline plot, but I couldn't find anything. I also searched through the Options Reference on the Dygraph website, but again to no avail.

The only thing I did find as smooth edges drawn with dygraph were some of the examples in their Example page, like this one for instance: http://dygraphs.com/gallery/#g/plotter (the blue and the purple line)

I looked at the code of that, but I couldn't figure out how it's made to look that way. The only hint I got was that Math.sin, Math.cos, Math.round and so on were used. But if I were to use those- that'd change the values in the data that I'm giving my chart, and I don't want that. I want to keep the values the way they are.

If anybody has any idea how I can achieve smooth edges and still keep my values the way they are- please do share. Thank you for reading!

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately spline plots are not possible in dygraphs (this is also stated [here](http://socialcompare.com/en/review/dygraphs)).

If you really want smooth edges without changing the values I suggest you use something like cubic spline interpolation. A nice article that can get you started can be found [here](http://blog.ivank.net/interpolation-with-cubic-splines.html).
So what you then do is that you generate these interpolation points for a large array of X-values.
Then you plot these values using dygraphs. Dygraphs still uses sharp edges to display the values, but because you generate these values for a large set of input values, the displayed line looks smooth.

Note: with cubic spline interpolation your data points are plotted without changing the exact values.

Answer (score 0):

See dygraphs issue on github:
**Smooth plotter using bezier curves #469**
It looks like Dan (dygraphs author) addressed this issue a few months after the OP's question.

https://github.com/danvk/dygraphs/pull/469

http://dygraphs.com/extras/